# Why do are the 'type' & 'removed' fields in receipt logs different between Ganache and Geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, ganache, logs, receipts

When I run a particular transaction and log the receipt, I am getting different results depending on if my EVM is Geth or Ganache.  Specifically, Ganache returns `receipt.logs[0].type: 'mined'` while in Geth, there is no `type` member of logs[0] and there is instead `receipt.logs[0].removed: 'false'` (the receipt from Ganache has no `removed` member.).  The rest of the receipt looks pretty similar between the two EVMs, ignoring member order.

Is there a reliable source about what fields my program should expect to find in an Ethereum transaction receipt?  If so, does one (or both) of these two implementations need a bug report for being inconsistent with that?

Comment: Probably geth should be the closest thing to a definition, from the ethereum wiki removed is defined but type is not https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getfilterchanges.